# How can I make a NSTextField clickable in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I make a NSTextField clickable in Cocoa?

I would like to invoke a method when such text field is clicked. I've bound it in interface builder but the method is never invoked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event `mouseDown`, NSTextField inherits from NSControl which has this event.

Comment: I've specified the delegate and implemented mouseDown but it is never invoked. Also, the mouse cursor when I move the arrow over the text is never a hand, but the default text cursor.

Comment: The same method is invoked for other objects having the same delegate. It seems some setting of NSTextField is wrong.

Comment: I use two methods: first - own class  inherited from NSTextField, or second - use this event on NSView, where  NSTextField is placed on.

Comment: I've done what you say, but the mouseDown method is invoked by any child of my window. So, how do I know when is the correct object instead ?

Comment: In first case it's obvious, in second I usually check position where view was clicked with frame of field.

Comment: It sounds like not a very good solution to check the position. I've opted for the first solution.

Comment: Yes and not :) Second option I've used for views where are many objects of different types.